# Достать атрибут value тега input

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

час уже мучаюсь!!

```
<form action="/asdfg?act=to_from&matc=hdsf76876786jn" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="11" />
<input type="hidden" name="mesg" value="6" />
<input type="hidden" name="sb_ject" value="4" />';
```

не могу выловить value="11"

пробывал так

```
preg_match('/value="(.*)" \/>/', $otvet, $from);
preg_match('/value="(.*)"/>/', $otvet, $from);
```

ну нивкакую!

Comment: $otvet === $result ??????

Answer (score 2):

Здесь лучше использовать функцию [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all).

```
<?php
 
$from = '<form action="/asdfg?act=to_from&matc=hdsf76876786jn" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="from" value="11" />
<input type="hidden" name="mesg" value="6" />
<input type="hidden" name="sb_ject" value="4" />';
preg_match_all('/value="(\d+)"/', $from, $otvet);
 
print_r($otvet);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => value="11"
            [1] => value="6"
            [2] => value="4"


        )
```

```
    [1] => Array

        (

            [0] => 11
```

```
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/riy108).

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте местами переменные `$from` и `$otvet` и идите читать документацию.

Comment: А не лучше ли посмотреть туториалы у пиндо, ладно американцев?